# Update angualar.js factory from chrome dev. tools

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-devtools, factory, angularjs-factory

Is there a way to override the downloaded `angular.js factory` from dev tools.

 I want to add some log statements from the client as I cannot do by deploying code. Normal Javascript functions could be updated easily just by running the updated function in console. 
 But, I am unable to do that for `angular.js factories`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general answer is there's no way. Angular [services are singletons](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services#services), and once the service was instantiated, [the instance is stored in private variable](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.6/src/auto/injector.js#L640) with no opportunity to override it.

However, if the factory was instantiated as an object with a bunch of methods, the methods can be monkey-patched:

```
var factory = angular.element(document.querySelector('.ng-scope'))
  .injector()
  .get('factoryName');

var factoryMethod = factory.methodName;
factory.methodName = function () {
  console.log(arguments);
  return factoryMethod.apply(factory, arguments);
};
```

In other cases the recipe is to hijack the app during bootstrapping process with Greasemonkey / Tampermonkey. This makes it possible to provide the entire new module that overrides components from the original module. Or provide an additional `config` block to the original module, where defined factory can be modified with [$provide.decorator](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#decorator) or redefined with [$provide.factory](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#factory).

Comment: How can I hijack app bootstrapping?

Comment: And, I am working on a chromium embedded application. I am not sure I could install plugns

Comment: Then you should check your options how you can add a script there to loading page.

Comment: It depends on where did you landed during page loading and how the app is bootstrapped. You can [plant a new module](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32656843/3731501) to existing one, or remove 'ng-app' attribute and do bootstrapping by yourself, or monkey-patch 'angular.bootstrap' method.

Comment: Thank you :)
How about modifying controller? Is it possible?

Comment: Existing controllers on the page? No. Controllers that will be instantiated after you overrode controller constructor? Yes, they can be redefined with $controller.